# Install "ibm_db2" extension for php on Linux?

Tags: php, db2

I'm currently working on a web project using DB2 database. What is the best way to install **ibm_db2** extension for PHP on Linux so that the application can take advantage of the native db2 functions.

Shown [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ibm-db2.php):  The generic ODBC driver is simply too slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use `pecl`

```
pecl install ibm_db2
```

Or download the driver and install manually following the guide here https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.cli.doc/doc/t0023864.html